# How do I fix this while loop and table?

Tags: c++, xcode, codeblocks

I am trying to write a code for a project and I am trying to make a while loop but it keeps repeating when I run it. I am also trying to get it to make a table but it wont show up either. Here is what I have so far.
Here is also the steps to see what I am trying to go for:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jFPR.png

```
#include<iostream> //Required for cout
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
const double h=1.3;
const double k= 0.3;
const double pi = 3.141593;
int main()
{


// Declare and initialize objects.
int time(0);
double t, SurfaceArea, Volume, Radius,InitialRadius , IR, R;
cout << "Hello user! please put in the Initial Radius ";

cin >> IR;
InitialRadius = IR;

cout << "Now please put in the time:";

cin >> t;


while (time <= 5.4)
{
cout<<"Time(sec) Radius (m) Surface area (m2) Volume (m3)";
cout << time << " " << Radius << " " << SurfaceArea << " " << 
Volume << endl;
Radius = k * InitialRadius*t;
SurfaceArea = pi*(pow(Radius*pow(t, 2)+pow(h,2),0.5));
Volume = 0.33 * pi*pow(Radius,2)*h;
time += 10;
}// end loop
// Exit program.
return 0;
} //end main
```

Comment: *I am trying to make a while loop but it keeps repeating when I run it.* This is pretty much the definition of a loop. That said, what's the relationship between `t` and `time`?

Comment: What happens when you step through with your debugger?

Comment: `while(t<=5.4)` -- you never modify `t` in the loop....

Comment: The program states that the while-loop should repeat as long as t is less or equal to 5.4. When or under what condition would you expect it to be less? First assume the program really does, what is stated, and think what else could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Things that are wrong (my machine refuses to compile it)

```
  double t, SurfaceArea, Volume, Radius,
    InitialRadius , IR, R, pi(2 * acos(0.0));
......
while (t <= 5.4)
{
    cout << "Time(sec) Radius (m) Surface area (m2) Volume (m3)";
    Radius = k * InitialRadius * t;  <<<== you never give InitalRadius a value
    SurfaceArea = pi * (pow(R * pow(t, 2) + pow(h, 2), 0.5)); <<< likewise R
    Volume = 0.33 * pi * pow(R, 2) * h;
    Time = Time + 0.19;   <<<<<<==== TIme is an integer adding 0.19 to it wont do anything
}
```

Fix those things for a start

Comment: Okay, I fixed those things. and I think the same happened before, to were the loop didn't go back to the first cout statement or give me a table

Comment: @MonaeSears please update the question with the corrected code.

Comment: I have updated my code and it produces a better outcome but the table is still showing zeros

Comment: @MonaeSears still not given R a value. Now also Surface Area , Radius, Vilume have not been given values.

Comment: They are supposed to be placeholder names and not have a value so the computer identifies it. And the initial radius along with the time is supposed to be given by the user

Answer (score 0):

It appears that 't' in your while loop never changes once it enters the loop. This will cause a infinite loop unless 't' is updated inside the loop. If 't' is supposed to change by +0.19, do

```
Time = Time+0.19; //change time to a double format, as integers do not allow decimals
t = time;
```

I believe IR is supposed to be InitialRadius, but it is not initialized to such. Do this after you input IR:

```
cin >> IR;
InitialRadius = IR;
```

R is not set to anything. If R is supposed to be Radius, make sure you set it as such:

```
R = Radius; //or just change the R's in your program to Radius
```

Are you trying to print out Time, Radius, Surface area, and Volume in table format? And are they supposed to be printed out each time the loop runs through? If so, you need to cout these as well.

```
cout << Time << " " << Radius << " " << SurfaceArea << " " << Volume << endl;
```

This will look something like:

```
Time(sec) Radius(m) Surface area (m2) Volume (m3)
# # # # //numbers here
```